# How to find offset position with touchmove?

Tags: javascript, css, offset, touchmove

I have a really simple code for dragging/moving an element via touchscreen. The code works fine, the only problem is a common problem, but no matter how I try I cannot fix the code to drag from the touchpoint. Instead every movement starts from the edge of the element regardless of initial touch position.

I have seen a few suggestions but all have failed. I am hoping the smaller simpler code will attract a simple fix.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
   <script>
    $("#drag").on('touchmove',function(e){


// This is supposed to be the fix, 
// but regardless of positioning 
// (relative parent) of the divs,
// it is failing ---


   var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relX =(e.clientX - offset.left);

// By rights the above is the correct solution. But I
// cannot suss out why it is not working.

   var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
    var x = touch.clientX

   $(this).css({
    "-webkit-transform": "translate3d("+ x +"px,"+ 0 +"px,0)"
    }); 
   });              
  </script>


  <! --And here is the html -->

<body>               
   <div id="container" class="container">              
    <div id='drag' class='drag'>               
    <!---contents--->                
    </div>                 
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
 position:relative;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0px;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 background: #ccc;
}

#drag {
 position:absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 10px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 10%;
 background: #0a0;
}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate by the way, this is a completely different code. And considering i am yet to meet the intelligence i require, i shall persist.

Comment: here is a jfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/xbmyazb2/22/

Comment: Very Close Call, But still not quite hitting the mark ... http://jsfiddle.net/415rxhgy/7/

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer, took a re-write and a little help from elsewhere.

But for anybody else who is in the same position one day and comes here for advice, you will find it here:

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    width:500px;
    height:100%;
}

.drag{
     position:absolute;
    top:1%; 
    left:1%;
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
    border-style: solid; 1px;
    border-color: blue;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

HTML.

```
<div id="container" class="container">

    <div id='drag' class='drag'>

   <center> ...content drag me... </center>

    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript.

```
<script>
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent scrolling of window while touchevent triggerd for element.
});

window.addEventListener('load', function(){   

    var box = document.getElementById('drag'), // the element or box
    bleft=0 , // left position of moving  element/box
    sx=150, // starting x touch point - half the element width is best. 
    ds = 0, // distance traveled by touch point
    tob = null // Touch object holder

    box.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
            var box = document.getElementById('drag'),
        tob = e.changedTouches[0] // reference first touch point for this event
        var ds = parseInt(tob.clientX) - sx // calculate dist traveled by touch point
        box.style.left = ( (bleft + ds > 400)? 400 : (bleft + ds < -10000000)? -10000000 : bleft + ds ) + 'px' // distance element can travel in X direction


    box.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
            var box = document.getElementById('drag'),
        tob = e.changedTouches[0] // reference first touch point
        bleft = parseInt(box.style.left) // get left position of box
        sx = parseInt(tob.clientX) // get x coord of touch point

    }, false) // return null activity or event if none


    }, false)

}, false)

</script>
```

Comment: If Anybody can update this so that the 1st touch-point corresponds to the users 1st touch-point instead of being a predefined. i feel the user would appreciate this if they ever should need this code..